# Can I use VxWorks OS as Normal OS on my PC?

Tags: operating-system, embedded, vxworks

I am New to VxWorks. First of all Can I use VxWorks OS as Normal OS on my PC? I mean Can I run my application software on VxWorks OS?

Answer (score 4):

While VxWorks can run on PC hardware, it is not a general-purpose OS for running independent executables.  VxWorks is an RTOS library; you statically link it to your application and the whole runs as a monolithic executable.

It does support a command line interface (intended primarily for development and debug), and from that it is possible to dynamically load and link object files, but these are not independent executables in the sense they are in a GPOS; they essentially become part of the monolithic application.

An RTOS such as OS/9 or QNX would be more suited as these can operate more like a GPOS in the sense of loading and executing independently linked executables.

In any event, application software must be specifically built for these targets.

Comment: Good answer - although it should also touch on RTPs, which are independent executables

Comment: @mjs : to be honest I have not used VxWorks in many years, since v5.x; the answer is likely incomplete or just plain wrong.  It may be useful for you to post an answer if you have more up-to-date information.

Answer (score 2):

For versions of VxWorks prior to VxWorks 6, the [answer by clifford](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45576326/2139094) provides a good explanation of why this is not really possible.

VxWorks 6 introduced Real Time Processes (RTPs). These are independant, user mode applications, running on top of the VxWorks OS. Dependant on how the VxWorks OS has been configured and built, these RTP applications may have access to POSIX libraries, and so you may be able to run POSIX applications (eg linux programs) with little modification.

However, these must still be built for VxWorks, ideally linked against your own VxWorks Source Build.

You cannot, however, just pick up any old application and expect it to run. You are never going to get Word or Excel to run.